# Can Juju be used for desktop setup automation?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, juju, desktop-environments, automation

I go through multiple Ubuntu Desktop (14 & 16) installs per year. I used them as application development environments so they get banged around a lot with little effort in trying to keep them running.

As I reinstall the OS and start to build out the system with the software I use, what software is needed, and custom preferences, I tend to perform repetitive tasks. I do know that there are a set of customizations, and software installs that will always be the same so I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to apply my settings other than writing a script or cloning. I'm curious if Juju would do the trick for this particular scenario. Performing these tasks in a programmatic way would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAAS sounds like a better fit for your needs.

MAAS does large-scale deploys of the operating system (Ubuntu, Windows, CentOS) and can use custom images. Seems like you want to make customer images that have all the packages installed, and then use a script for local customization post-install.

See http://maas.io/